# Every time im running removeElement, it clears my state

Tags: typescript, react-native, api

When i press my `fetchApi` button, a new address appears, and if i keep pressing, it keeps adding more address, but when i press the `removeElement` button, it deletes all the addresses, how can i make it so it only removes the one im pressing?

```
  const removeElement = (index) => {
    const newData = [];
    setAllData(newData);
  };

  const fetchApi = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await axios
        .get("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/addresses")
        .then((response) => {
          setAllData([...allData, response.data]);

          console.log(response.data);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchApi}>funciona pls</button>
        {allData.map((data) => (
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              padding: 16,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 20
            }}
          >
            <p>
              <strong>Address: {data.street_address}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>City: {data.city}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Street Name: {data.street_name}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Zipcode: {data.zip_code}</strong>
            </p>
            <button onClick={removeElement}>botao</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `removeElement` method, you are setting your state `allData` to an empty array. Every time you run `removeElement` you will be clearing your state.

If each element in `allData` has a unique id, your `removeElement` method could look something like this:

```
const removeElement = (id) => {
  const newData = allData.filter(element => element.id === id);
  setAllData(newData);
};
```

And your component:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchApi}>funciona pls</button>
        {allData.map((data) => (
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              padding: 16,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 20
            }}
          >
            <p>
              <strong>Address: {data.street_address}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>City: {data.city}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Street Name: {data.street_name}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Zipcode: {data.zip_code}</strong>
            </p>
            <button onClick={()=>removeElement(data.id)}>botao</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
```

Comment: each element in allData has an id (its an array btw), i tried what you said, but it does not work.

Comment: I forgot to add more to my answer. You need to pass the id to the removeElement function in your map.

Comment: I fixed it, i wasn't passing the parameter to the button. but thank you so much